# Proper NumberFormat in VBA-excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I know at first this question sound easy.

I want to have a high comma after the third digit. For example: 10'000 or 1'000 and 100 and 10. I am able to do this manually in excel using "Format">"Number"> 0 "decimals". That gives me the right formatting. But now comes the twist! If I record the a macro of that action the code is something like this:

```
MyChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "#'##0"
```

But this yields something else when a applied, namely : 100'000 10'000 1'000 **'100 '10**

[image: Here is what I get with "#'##0"]

**Any suggestions on what format code to use ?** I could always go through all ticklables check the value and format it indivdually but that's a pain. If I do not have to I'd rather not do it.

Comment: I suppose that you should use "#,##0" where comma marks thousand seperator that in your operating system settings can be defined as apostrophe. I don't know how format if you want different than in system settings.

Comment: @GrzesiekDanowski Perfect! Works! Put it as an answer. The macro recorder is useful but not without flaws unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you should use "#,##0" where comma marks thousand seperator that in your operating system settings can be defined as apostrophe.
I don't know how format if you want different than in system settings.
Reference: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the thousands separator in Excel from default `,` to `'` use

```
Application.ThousandsSeparator = "'" 
Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```

Then

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
```

will produce

[image]

Note that this will change the thousands separator in your complete Excel (not only that workbook).

---

Alternatively you can change it system wide in your system settings.